# Import json array of objects using react hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json

I was searching an entire day to add some categories from a JSON file using React hooks, with no luck so far.
I am hoping that anyone can help me with this.
Here is how the JSON it looks:

```
{
"shoes": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sneakerși piele Massimo Dutti",
            "price": 135,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Rz8lVQa.jpg",
            "size": 45,
            "colour": "Negru",
            "material": "Piele",
            "brand": "Massimo Dutti",
            "description": "Sneakerși din piele cu talpă inițial albă, din colecția de toamnă-iarnă 2019, Massimo Dutti."
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Teniși negri Polo Ralph Lauren",
            "price": 100,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Og3Oh24.jpg",
            "size": 45,
            "colour": "Negru",
            "material": "Pânză",
            "brand": "Polo Ralph Lauren",
            "description": "Teniși din pânză cu talpă inițial albă, din colecția de primăvară-vară 2019, Fashion Days."
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Ghete din piele maro Massimo",
            "price": 185,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/zoqSu87.jpg",
            "size": 45,
            "colour": "Maro",
            "material": "Piele",
            "brand": "Massimo Dutti",
            "description": "Ghete maro din piele, din colecția de toamnă-iarnă 2017, Massimo Dutti."
        }
    ],
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/X0qldXO.jpg",
    "name": "Încălțăminte",
    "description": "Ghete, pantofi, sneakerși: finețe garantată!"
},
"sweaters": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Pulovăr finuț cu guler",
            "price": 95,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/6afzuEr.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Maro",
            "material": "Cașmir",
            "brand": "DS Damat",
            "description": "Pulovăr din cașmir, slim fit, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2019, DS Damat."
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Pulovăr multicolor",
            "price": 105,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/s0VytKc.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Multicolor",
            "material": "Bumbac",
            "brand": "McNeal",
            "description": "Pulovăr multicolor, colecția toamnă-iarnă 209, McNeal."
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Pulovăr călduros și frumos",
            "price": 165,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/BWGgzlK.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Multicolor",
            "material": "Lână",
            "brand": "SELECTED",
            "description": "Pulovăr din lână, în carouri, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2019, SELECTED."
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Pulovăr din lână",
            "price": 160,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/dTcMbHT.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Crem",
            "material": "Lână",
            "brand": "Massimo Dutti",
            "description": "Pulovăr din lână cu model, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2019, Massimo Dutti."
        }
    ],
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/SZU7liE.jpg",
    "name": "Pulovere",
    "description": "Pulovărașe elegănțele, slim, clasă superioară."
},
"pants": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Blugi bleumarin slim fit",
            "price": 35,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/VhpATO8.jpg",
            "size": "34",
            "colour": "Bleumarin închis",
            "material": "Blug",
            "brand": "DS Damat",
            "description": "Blugi bleumarin, slim fit, colecția primăvară-vară 2019, DS Damat."
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Blugi negri slim fit",
            "price": 40,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/weiI07t.jpg",
            "size": "34",
            "colour": "Negru-gri",
            "material": "Blug",
            "brand": "DS Damat",
            "description": "Blugi negri, slim fit, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2019, DS Damat."
        }
    ],
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/srQCDRN.jpg",
    "name": "Pantaloni/blugi",
    "description": "Jeanși și pantaloni pentru baieții care și-o ard patroni!"
},
"jackets": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Haină lungă din lână virgină",
            "price": 210,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/IXrZitQ.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Gri închis",
            "material": "Lână virgină",
            "brand": "Peek and Cloppenburg",
            "description": "Haină lungă din lână virgină, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2018, Peek and Cloppenburg."
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Geacă bleumarin cu glugă detașabilă",
            "price": 250,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/eCZd7PU.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Bleumarin",
            "material": "Poliester",
            "brand": "DS Damat",
            "description": "Geacă bleumarin cu glugă detașabilă, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2019, DS Damat."
        }
    ],
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/81I6Oab.jpg",
    "name": "Geci/Haine",
    "description": "Confortabile, călduroase și nu arăți ca un cartof!"
},
"tshirts": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Tricou în dungi",
            "price": 90,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/BWvzCwB.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Multicolor",
            "material": "Bumbac",
            "brand": "Lacoste",
            "description": "Tricou în dungi, colecția primăvară-vară 2019, Lacoste."
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Tricou de ping pong",
            "price": 110,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/4BbF4TO.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Roșu",
            "material": "Poliester",
            "brand": "Li Ning",
            "description": "Tricou de ping pong cu imprimeu cu dragon, purtat de jucatorii naționalei chinei în 2013."
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Tricou original BVB cu autograf",
            "price": 1909,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/etIsbHV.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Galben-Negru",
            "material": "Poliester",
            "brand": "Puma",
            "description": "Tricoul purtat de Borussia Dortmund în sezonul competițional 2018-2019, cu numarul 7 și numele 'SANCHO'. Tricoul este semnat de portarul Borussiei, Roman Burki."
        }
    ],
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/l27WtFL.jpg",
    "name": "Tricouri",
    "description": "Și de băiețeală și de sport."
},
"accesories": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "Fular TJ cu două fețe",
            "price": 85,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/rSVUiLO.jpg",
            "size": "Universal",
            "colour": "Gri-Bleumarin",
            "material": "Cașmir",
            "brand": "Trussardi Jeans",
            "description": "Fular cu imprimeu, din colecția toamnă-iarnă 2018, Trussardi Jeans."
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Mănuși din piele",
            "price": 60,
            "currency": "LEI",
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/LbjGaZ1.jpg",
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "Negru",
            "material": "Piele",
            "brand": "DS Damat",
            "description": "Mănuși din piele, cu model, din colecția toamnă-iarnă 2018, DS Damat."
        }
    ],
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/qw3wDj8.jpg",
    "name": "Accesorii",
    "description": "Fulare, căciuli, mănuși: nu mai sta pe gânduri, cumpără-le acuși!"
}
```

I managed to map the objects with states, but I want to do it by using hooks. Can anyone help me refactor the code to work the same way but using hooks?

```
import products from '../utils/products.json';
import HomeCategory from '../components/HomeCategory';

class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            categories: []
        }
    }
componentDidMount() {
    const categories = Object.keys(products);
    this.setState({categories});
}

render() {
    return(

            <div className="container-fluid container-min-max-width">
                <div className="row">
                    {this.state.categories.map((category, index) =>
                        <HomeCategory
                            key={index}
                            route={category}
                            name={products[category].name}
                            description={products[category].description}
                            image={products[category].image}
                        />
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need a state. You could move `categories` out your component (because json is not going to change and doesn't depend on anything) and just use this variable to iterate by.

```
import products from '../utils/products.json'
import HomeCategory from '../components/HomeCategory'

const categories = Object.keys(products)

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid container-min-max-width">
      <div className="row">
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
          <HomeCategory
            key={index}
            route={category}
            name={products[category].name}
            description={products[category].description}
            image={products[category].image}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: WOW, so many hours of searching, and the solution was that simple.